# Man ignore his wife and refuse to have any relation with her because of her healthy problems

Tags: halal-haram

One brother who married with a woman 3 years ago refuse to kiss her wife because he says that she has a bad breath (halitosis) and he refuse to have any intimate contact to her because he says she has trush.
She is suffering because of that, and the husband is ignoring her.
My question it's is legal to refuse to have any contact to your wife/husband for this healthy reasons?
Thanks for your answer

---

I mean if is good to ignore and refuse to stay with your partner(wife or husband) because the other has any healthy problem like the ones I tell before.
Sorry  English it's not my first lenguaje and maybe I didn't explain myself well.
Thanks for the answer.

Comment: السلام عليكم ورحمة الله وبركاته What do you mean by legal?

Answer (score -1):

In Islam, husband must an intimate contact (specifically direct sex) at least once per 4 months. Exceeding 4 months gives the wife the right in Islam with the option to discontinue marriage.

Regarding his claims about bad mouth smell, the wife should take care of her mouth and clean her body to be looking as beatiful as possible. She should even try more hard to attract him with some suitable clothes and make-up. Women in islam is not prohibited from initiating sex and trying to Penis foreplay (sorry), also.

If the husband even continued to ignore her after looking good, she must wait up to 4 months maximum, then she has the right to discontinue with him. The husband is responsible about all money and related issues if he refused to have sex, and he must then give her wife all her rights including children care.

References:

- https://islamqa.info/en/answers/1078/how-often-are-husband-and-wife-supposed-to-have-intercourse

Comment: Please consider supporting your claims by evidences.

Comment: 4 months is false

Comment: @MAS Kindly read before attacking ! https://www.alro7.net/ayaq.php?langg=english&aya=226&sourid=2

Comment: @FindOutIslamNow, your comment is greatly false. Older people don't have sex for years. Come to common sense. Sex is mutual understanding, if both husband and wife decide not to have sex, it is perfect. Why are you complicating the matter. I am attacking but raising your false propaganda